# Kubernetes Statefulset, can you have both load balancing (clusterip) and a headless service at the same time?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I'm in the process of studying Statefulsets in Kubernetes, and I'm having an issue understanding if load balancing is possible (for the classic case that each pod has its own PVC and there is a syncing process of each new pod from the previous one).

From what I've learned, the master pod is the one performing the "writes" (but can also do reads), and the other slave pods (pod-1, pod-2, etc...) can only do reads.

A Headless service in that case would be a service used for syncing the data between the pods, since it exposes the DNS names of all the pods under the Statefulset (and for writing data as I assume).

But I heard very little about also using a ClusterIP service for load balancing, why?

Is it possible? If so, I would like to know if my assumption for such approach is correct:

1. Read: ClusterIP can be used for reading data for load balancing
2. Write: Can be done only via the headless service (or other means if outside the cluster)

My problem with this approach, is that even if it is correct, other apps connection to the data bases have to know these details in order not to corrupt the data.

What would be the best solution for such a case, what could I be missing?

Thank you,

Ariel

Comment: To get a better understanding, are you trying to deploy a database or what application are we talking about here?

Comment: I'm generally asking about load balancing limits. So to answer your question, yes I am asking about databases, but soon enough my question will be about an application that would have volume claim. So in general, I would like to understand when load balancing is impossible and why, and when it is - how and why would it be possible

Comment: You can have both headless service and a load balancer for the same statefulset however, here you will be dealing with the individual pods. Go through the blog **[Exposing kubernetes statefulsets](https://itnext.io/exposing-statefulsets-in-kubernetes-698730fb92a1)** written by `Bob Killen` where he clearly explained how to use both headless service and load balancer for statefulsets.

Comment: @KranthiveerDontineni I went through the blog today, and it was nice to know that I can expose the Statefulset pods individually, but I didn't mean Loadbalancer as type of service, but rather as a service that literally load balances - the same way a normal clusterIP would do that.